# Npgsql first connection takes a long time

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 9.3 and npgsql 2.1.3 on Windows with .NET 4.0. I installed PostgreSQL with default settings and running as a service. I use Npgsql in a WPF project in order to test Binding the data to a ListBox control. I put the dataset and related code in a Buttons eventhandler method (for Click event).

The problem is, first connection attempt is very slow (more than a minute, may be two minutes sometimes). Of course second and later connection attempts are quite faster than the first. However, when I close the widget that contains the button and create/show new widget (the widget containing the button) the same problem occurs. I know this is not a best practice, but I just wanted to test it and surprised due to this long connection time.

The test code in the button eventhandler is;

```
DataSet dset = new DataSet();
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection();
NpgsqlDataAdapter adapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();

conn.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;Database=test;User Id=postgres;Password=pass;Pooling=False;SSL=False;";
adapter.SelectCommand = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT * FROM  \"Personel\"");
adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = conn;
conn.Open();

MessageBox.Show("End of open");
```

Comment: Start by set a breakpoint on the conn.ConnectionString and go line by line. Which line takes more time?

Comment: Of course on line "conn.Open();". Until calling Open() everything is quite normal. May be I missed some point in your comment?

Comment: I see a problem with you code. Why you open the connection After setting the conection of the adapter? I'm trying to see if the problem is with open method of the connection or with the execution of the command.

Comment: ericpap, Is that matter (order) in that case, because this just a test? Moreover, I found the problem, when I removed the MessageBox it worked as expected. A little bit weird, but I do not know the reason.

Comment: Then you didn't do what i suggest with the breakpoint or you would see that. Are your code inside a DLL or library?

Comment: I did it, before you suggest, but to be honest I did not realize it during the first try. The code is in a simple/single assembly (WPF application) not in a DLL. I call the method in the GUI thread, which is not good of course and the point I suspect.

Comment: Well i don't know why it takes the extra time. I suspect that it has to be related to the process thread related with msgbox.

Comment: Long first connection, multiple minutes. Hmm, broken dns resolver?